# Regex: Copy a word/string in a line above to below

Tags: regex

Can someone please help me with a find and replace Regex for this?  I want to copy whatever text comes after PREOP Dx to replace the word "Same" in POSTOP Dx:

```
PREOP Dx:  Hypertension.
POSTOP Dx:  Same
```

MUST BECOME

```
PREOP Dx:  Hypertension.
POSTOP Dx:  Hypertension.
```

Comment: @RobertLongson You write asking him what language. What on earth,.. just give him a regex, it doesnt matter. If one software  or language uses $1 $2 $2 and another uses \1 \2 \3.  If you are thinking oh one might not support negative lookbehind.. you dont need that for this.  And if you think you did then say so and that only some will support it. And if you can do it with or without a higher level regex feature then show with and without it

Comment: quick answer is to use `(........)` and include searching for new lines e.g. \r\n or \n. So once you have the whole thing matched with each component in parentheses then you can write \1 \2 \3   \r\n or \n, etc in the replace portion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the job:

- Find: `PREOP Dx: (.+)\RPOSTOP Dx: \KSame`
- Replace: `$1`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/iHpGBS/1)

---

If your regex falvour doesn't support `\K`, you can use:

- Find: `(PREOP Dx: (.+)\RPOSTOP Dx: ) Same`
- Replace: `$1$2`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/xn2Iv8/1)

Comment: I'm using an application called BatchDocs from BinaryMark to do a find and replace in text files using RegEx and when I tried the RegEx given above I got an error message:  Error: Invalid search pattern: parsing "PREOP Dx:(.+)\RPOSTOP Dx:\KSame" - Unrecognized escape sequence \R

Comment: @GeorgePatronus: See my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but I'm now getting this message - Error: Invalid search pattern: parsing "PREOP Dx:(.+)\RPOSTOP Dx:)Same" - Unrecognized escape sequence \R

Comment: @GeorgePatronus: Replace `\R` with `\r?\n`

Comment: Tried this, did not get any error message, but no replacement happened. :-(

Comment: Tried this as well but again no replacement happened (PREOP Dx:\s+)(.+)\n(POSTOP Dx:\s+)([^\s]+) Substitution $1$2\n$3$2

Comment: @GeorgePatronus: Well, I don't know BatchDocs. May be they use specific regex. Do you have some documentation that say something about regex it uses?

Comment: their website has no info but the action sequences get saved with a .tlpx extension.